# QGIS WMS Server always throw "connection to proxy refuse"

Tags: qgis

and this is my config:
[image]

and this is my error take my so much thime:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Kindly add some context to your problem. It will help understand the problem more clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved. If you have same problem, you can adjust QGIS web proxy.

[image]